# Ethernet not working when powered over GPIO

Tags: gpio, power-supply, ethernet

I'm powering my RPi (rev 2, model B) through GPIO pins - same connection like [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/1589) - using it ethernet is not working, though the ethernet works fine when powered through the microUSB port.

The problem seems to be some kind of under-voltage in Ethernet connector. I saw this happens to some people with USB, and the solution is simple - [solder a connection between GPIO and USB directly](http://hackaday.com/2012/09/04/problems-powering-raspberry-pi-from-gpio-header/).

But I can't find any solution for ethernet - could there be one similar to the one for USB? The Pi's schematics are too difficult for me to read.

So, what to do? (to power it with microUSB is NOT a solution for me)

Comment: I power via the 5V and ground pins on P1.  I have no problem with the USB or Ethernet.  Is the voltage too low or the amperage not sufficient?

Comment: The ethernet __IS__ powered by the usb system, as it's technically a usb ethernet device (a major reason the RPi is terrible at network operations involving speed or volume).

Comment: This is peculiar. Are you wiring the positive and negative to the GPIO. Maybe there is a ground loop. Make sure no other power supply is connected, like to a USB HUB or something else. Are you using the same power supply or another. You can check the voltage with a multimeter and the best to use a 2A supply.

Comment: Did you fix this? :)

Comment: Hello Simon, any good news or new findings? Feel free to share your experience writing your own answer.

Comment: GPIO-powered Pi works like a charm to me (tested on B, B+, B2). IMHO there is some issue with power supply used by topicstarter.

Comment: Can you give the power caracteristics that you are providing to GPIO Pins? Amps and Voltage?? Do you have @ least 2A?

Answer (score -1):

Using GPIO pins to power ethernet is **too weak** for the pi to handle, you will need a micro USB adapter. GPIO pins do not have enough voltage to support the whole pi. If I was you, I would get a MicroUSB cable, its the only way if you don't have wireless.

Comment: I am afraid that the OP is not talking about GPIO pins when saying "GPIO pins" but about the voltage pins at the same connector. Unfortunately such sloppy notations have become widespread.